# Slack API not accepting \n for new line when using slash commands

Tags: slack-api, slack

I've built a simple slack integration (slash command) to return names from my table. The result should look like

Name1

Name2

Name3

For this i simply generate a text string like this:

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    $text .= $name . ' \n';
}
```

The integration itself is working fine, however the result looks like this

Name1 \nName2\n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like this is an [issue](https://github.com/cleentfaar/slack/issues/21) in slack.

Apparently it can be solved by using double quotes as such: `"\n"`.

Your code will become:

```
foreach($names as $name) {
    $text .= $name . "\n";
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!